# How many resources are enough?

Tags: mass-effect-2

It seems most planets I come across begin as being "Rich" in resources.  And Palladium in particular is *extremely* abundant.  However, probes aren't free and I haven't found an in-game mechanic for translating surplus resources into credits.  Fortunately, I'm fairly certain that the number of items to be bought with these resources *is* finite.  (That is, if you ignore the fact that certain ship & crew "upgrades" can be re-purchased infinitely.)

So, I'd like to know how much of each resource is needed to research all available upgrades to their maximum level, and to use each re-spec/re-train upgrade once.

In my case, I'm playing a new copy of Mass Effect 2 on the PS3.  This includes the Cerberus Network DLC (which includes several component DLCs) and Lair of the Shadow Broker.

Comment: For what it's worth, Lair of the Shadow Broker provides a way to gain resources that is not probe dependent (though it may take a loooong time on its own).

Comment: @RavenDreamer Could you refresh my memory, how?

Comment: @GarethJones There is a delivery to the terminals after you depose the shadow broker. This can be 2,000 of any resource (including Eezo).

Comment: @RavenDreamer Ah ok, wait does that happen every time after as well?

Comment: @GarethJones I don't know when it resets, but it *does* reset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is taken from the mass effect 2 wiki:

> Know that it only takes 195,000 Palladium, 275,000 Platinum, 220,000
>   Iridium, and 31,000 Element Zero (+5000 for every Bonus training and
>   +2500 for every retraining of powers and skills) to purchase EVERY research project in the game

However, if you count in the rewards for missions and assignments:

> Mining isn't the only income for resources. If every mission and
>   assignment is completed, and all resources on the mission are
>   collected, only 166000 Palladium, 243000 Platinum, 191000 Iridium, and
>   23000 Element Zero (+5000 for every Bonus training and +2500 for every
>   retraining of powers and skills) need to be collected. An additional
>   50000 less is required in each if a Mass Effect 2 play-through has
>   been completed, meaning that with this bonus there is no need to mine
>   Element Zero.

Thus:

195,000 Palladium, 275,000 Platinum, 220,000 Iridium, and 33,500 Element Zero is needed in total for every project + 1 power / skill retraining.

Taken from [here](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Planet_Scanning#Scanning_Tips)